# Is there a way to define an alias that executes a bin from a specific folder in MacOS?

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems, exec, zsh

I am currently using a Macbook Pro running MacOS Mojave 10.14.3. I have recently gotten into ruby programming but find their whole gem package management a little confusing. When i `gem install` a package, it installs it in my `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin` folder and if I want to execute a gem or get a gem version, for example the `solargraph` gem, I must type a command: `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/solargraph -v`. I was wondering if there is way for me to define an alias for the path `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin` so that I could type something like `gemexec solargraph -v` which would achieve the same result as `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/solargraph -v`. Thanks for your help. BTW I am using the ZSH shell.

Comment: You could make a function that takes in the gem name as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a function that will do this for you and place it in your .zshrc file.

```sh
function gemexec() {
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/"$1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks this seems like what I was looking for but there is still a problem. Defining this function and running `gemexec solargraph -v` ignores the `-v` flag and treats the input as `gemexec solargraph`. Is there a way to pass flags as well using this function approach?

Comment: You can add a space and “$2” to the function

Comment: Oh nice thanks. I attempted to generalize this to any number of flags and attempted to write some bash script myself but since I am new to this, the script doesn't seem to work: This is what i wrote:

Comment: This throws a bad substituion error. I am so sorry for the bad formatting. I dont know how to paste code in comments

Comment: <code> 
 function gemexec() {
       local execcommand
       if [ $# -eq 0 ];then
           echo "A Gem Name Required"
       elif [ $# -ge 1 ];then
           $execcommand=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/"$1"
           if [ $# -gt 1 ];then
               for i in {2..$#};do
                   local temp=$execcommand
                  $execcommand="$temp ${$i}"
              done
          fi
      fi
      echo $execcommand
 }

<\code>

Comment: Amend your posting to provide the code; as a comment, it is not really readable.  Also point out on which line you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that Ruby 'install' the binary to central bin directory located at `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/RUBY_VERSION/bin`.

Use `gem environment` to determine your path:

```
gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.3 (2018-10-18 patchlevel 105) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/alice/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/alice/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3_1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
     - /Users/alice/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3_1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

Then, you can add ruby `bin` path into your global `bin` path and to get what you want -

```
PATH="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bin:$PATH"
solargraph -v
0.31.3
```

Finally, to make `zsh` to use this PATH every time you open a shell, add this line into your .zsh_rc file -

```
echo PATH="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But what i was trying to accomplish was have a specific keyword that would be responsible for triggering the gems as u can with `npx` in node. Thanks again :D